# async function not listing anything

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

I need to list some users in this page but it just isnt workin

export default class Dermatologistas extends Component{
state ={
errorMessage: null,
users: []
}

```
  getUserList = async () => {
    console.log('ok1')
```

here it console logs normally

```
    try {
      const response = await api.get('/projects/list');
```

but here nothing happens

```
      const { users } = response.data
      console.log(response.data)
      console.log('ok')
      this.setState({ users });
     
    } catch (response) {
      this.setState({ errorMessage: response.data.error });
    }
  };
```

as you can see Im calling my function here

```
  componentDidMount(){
    this.getUserList()
  }

  render(){
    const users = this.state.users
    console.log(users)
    return(
      <View >
        { this.state.errorMessage && <Text>{ this.state.errorMessage }</Text> }
        {this.state.users.filter(user => user.speciality === 'Dermatologista').map(user => (
          <View key={user._id} style={{marginTop: 15, alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize:20}}>{user.title}</Text>
            <Text>{user.speciality}</Text>
            <Button   title = 'View Profile'onPress ={() => 
               this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}/>
            </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try [useEffect()](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) and [useState()](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

The use of componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate and others is obsolete.

you can try this now

```js
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const YourComponent = () => {
  
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('ok1')
    api.get('/projects/list').then((response) => {
      setUsers(response.data);
      console.log(response.data);
      console.log('ok');
    });
  }, []);
 
  return(
   <YourJsxComponents />
  );
};
```

OBS:by default useEffect is already an asynchronous function

Comment: show the error then, so i can know how to help give more details

Comment: it just dont show nothing man, it dont alert an error or something like that., thank you a lot for your help, and I also dont know whats the error, but it didnt solved

Comment: have you arrived yet if your api is returning the correct values through GET? or if you have an authentication key if it is correct

Comment: yeah, the api is working and the token too ; )

Comment: can you show only "console.log(response)"? or "console.log(response.data);"

Comment: you try this? `await api.get('/projects/list').then((response) => console.log(response));` It is other than `const response = await api.get('/projects/list');`

Comment: going to try now